# Find image edges in R plot

Tags: r, image-processing, edge-detection

I have made image matrix with readTIFF (from tiff package), and I'm curious how image edges of basic shapes could be located in the matrix? The matrix contains intensity values, so the image represent is grayscale. I know that I could visualize them using contours, but I could not figure it out how to make a new matrix just with binary values 0 - no border, 1 - border.
I have tried many different approaches, using kmeans, etc. with various recipes I have found online, but stayed pretty puzzled about this. My example picture was generated using the Gimp, containing letters and some random noise.

My working image: 
[image: tiff image]

[See it on the full page here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0nxV8GYm7F2ZVBDa19UaFNqbDQ/view)

Comment: Take a look at bioconductor's [EBimage](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html). I tried it on your example but couldn't get it to work very well, and even on higher res images I could only detect one letter, but maybe you have better luck.

Comment: EBImage is great, but I thought this issue could be solved more R-ishly, using basic framework. _Contour_ doing the job graphically, but I cannot find a method which returns _contour_ data as matrix, or list...